# Highlight/Select word and put brackets or " around it VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide, visual-studio-2019

VSC allows, to mark one or multiple words and put e.g. brackets around them or "", by simply "writing" (, { or ". I love this feature and I'm missing it in VS 2019. Is there any setting I haven't seen when looking into this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can install the [Selection Wrapper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EricMartineau.sw111) extension to wrap selected text depending on the key pressed.

Comment: Ya, that’s the only thing I found. I just feel the other one to be more effective. But then I’ll go with these shortcuts. Still good. Thanks!